# bootstrap 3 responsive table with fixed first column and table height fixed

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I need small help for bootstrap 3 responsive table with fixed first column and table height fixed. I am fixing table height at table level but i am unable to fix. Can you guys help on this.

Comment: Please show us your code.

Comment: link i am using http://jsfiddle.net/4XG7T/3/